# metaobj point as object

Tags: metapost

i give a first look to metaobj package and i try to define a triangle (almost as in the manual). So here's the **EDIT** (fpast request) code :

```
input metaobj;

vardef newTriangle@# text options=
  ExecuteOptions(@#)(options);
  assignObj(@#,"Triangle");
  StandardInterface;
  %%
  forsuffixes $ = suba,subb,subc :
    save $;
    string $;
    $ = newobjstring_;
    ObjPoint $;
    SubObject($,obj($));
  endfor;
  %
  ObjCode StandardEquations,
    "obj(@#subb) - obj(@#suba) = (5cm,0)",
    "obj(@#subc) - obj(@#subb) = (0,3cm)",
    "obj(@#subc)  = (obj(@#suba)+obj(@#subb)+obj(@#subc)) / 3",
    "@#ne = obj(@#subc)";
  StandardTies;
enddef;  

vardef drawTriangle (suffix n) =
  draw obj(n.suba)--obj(n.subb)--obj(n.subc)--cycle;
enddef;

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

vardef newTrianglee@# text options =
  ExecuteOptions(@#)(options);
  assignObj(@#,"Trianglee");
  StandardInterface;
  ObjPoint c,sa,sb,sc;
  ObjCode StandardEquations,
    "@#sb - @#sa = (5cm,0)",
    "@#sc - @#sb = (0,3cm)",
    "@#c  = (@#sa+@#sb+@#sc) / 3",
    "@#ne = @#sc";
  StandardTies;
enddef;  

vardef drawTrianglee (suffix s) =
  draw s.sa--s.sb--s.sc--cycle;
enddef;

%%% error ... or not
test = 0;

beginfig(1);
  if test=1 :
    newTriangle.u
  else :
    newTrianglee.u
  fi;
  u.c = origin;
  drawObj(u)
endfig;
end
```

But the compilation returns :

```
******* metaobj 0.93 (c) D. Roegel (2006/12/03) *******
)
>> -_______a+_______b
>> (141.73225,0)
! Equation cannot be performed (numeric=pair).
<to be read again> 
                   ;
code_function_->...bb)-obj((SUFFIX2)suba)=(5cm,0);
                                              obj((SUFFIX2)subc)-obj((SU...
<to be read again>
```

etc.

The code actually works if i do not use ObjPoint as subobjects so i guess this is the problem. But i can't figure out why ?

Thanks fo any help

**Edit** i noticed i've forgot `StandardEquations` in `ObjCode` command but truth is out there...

**Edit 2** edit code (fpast request) : choose `test=0` for successfull compilation with object Trianglee and `test=1` fo failed compilation

Comment: Could you please provide a minimal example (if not fully working), such as it can be compiled "out of the box"? For example, you forgot at least _input metaobj;_ at the beginning of your file.